# Unregistering a BroadcastReceiver from a non-Activity on Android

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I have an Android library that requires a BroadcastReceiver, which I register in an object constructor. It performs actions on that object based on changing internet state. But, I'm encountering error messages about a leaked receiver, because I don't call unregister.

How and where can I call unregister when I have no information on when the Activity would end? Since I am only providing the class that would be instantiated by an Activity, so no onPause, onClose methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try saving your receiver in a static. I think only get this error if you register the same receiver twice.

If that fails, you might also try calling context.getApplicationContext().registerBroadcastReceiver() instead of using the activity context.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be extending `Activity`, working properly with Android's workflow, and then have your users extend your Activity?

It's just a suggestion, but it would definitely solve the problem you're describing since you could register the receiver on `onCreate()` and unregister it on `onDestroy()`.